# How to open a video file directly from FastStone Capture into FastStone Video Editor?

Tags: faststone-capture

FastStone Capture has a built-in Video Editor, that can only be opened by loading a file into FastStone Screen Recorder, `FSRecorder.exe`

Is there any way to open a video file into FS Video Editor directly from File Explorer "Open With" or something, like a command line?

```
FSRecorder.exe myvideo.mp4
```

This doesnt work.